# Where was Takan's blood gem kept in the Black Magician Trilogy?

Tags: trudi-canavan, black-magician

During the events of the Black Magician Trilogy, The High Lord Akkarin mentions that he communicates with his servant Takan using a Blood Gem, which is created using forbidden Black Magic.

Where does Takan hide this gem? I didn't find any reference to where it was hidden in the text.

Comment: I don't think it's ever explicitly stated. I'll check the passages where Lorlen is first given a gem to see if he talks about seeing one on Takan. But otherwise I think it is simply hidden in plain sight. No one really knows what Blood Gems are at this point. It would simply be unremarkable jewelry.

Comment: Thanks alot for the feedback. It is good to know there are active Canavan community readers

Answer (score 1):

I have recently read the Black Magician Trilogy, and I do not believe any precise information is given as to where Takan's wears his blood gem. We are only told that it is "hidden".

Blood gems are small stones that must be in contact with the wearer's skin to function. For this reason they are often worn as rings, although to maintain contact with the skin the mounting must be rather unusual:

> She [Sonea] noted how the gem protruded from the inner side of the band,
> allowing it to touch the skin of the wearer

Cery was duped into wearing a blood gem when he was presented with a pendant, the ruby on it actually being a blood gem. Takan, however, does not wear a ring, and is not described as having any other type of jewelry:

> "And... Takan?" she frowned. "He doesn't wear a ring though." 
> "No he doesn't. **Takan's gem is hidden**."

Earlier in *The High Lord* we encounter an assassion who has a blood gem hidden inside a false tooth. Plausibly Takan's gem is also hidden in this way. But it could also be in contact with any other part of his anatomy that is not visible.

Comment: I don't really see the point of down-voting this. If the information is not given in the text, then it is not given, disappointing as it may be.

Answer (score -2):

I always assumed it was really small and hidden in a hollowed tooth or something so it will always be in contact with him

Comment: Do you have any evidence you could [edit] in to back this up? Or at least why you assumed this?

Comment: I'm currently re-reading The Novice, but if I see the passage that made me think that when I get to it in The High Lord I'll let you know, off the top of my head though I think it was partly because he said he had a gem hidden when he talks to the Thieves and also because when Akkarin shows Sonea the slave assassin, his blood gem is in a gold tooth to hide it, so just made sense to me that it was something like that so it would never be taken if Takan was arrested or searched